# Determine the "Luck" of a string

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string, return that string's "luck".

A string's luck, as I completely just made up for the purpose of this challenge, is an integer, determined as so:

- The base luck for a string is 1.
- For each consecutive letter it shares with the word "lucky" (case insensitive), multiply the luck by 2. For instance, if your string was "**lu**mberjack" or "sma**ck**" you'd multiply by 4. (More specifically, 2^number of consecutive characters shared.)

  - The shared letters have to be in the same consecutive order it appears in "lucky" but can start anywhere in the word for the same value ("luc" has the same 8* multiplier as "cky").
  - If the word has multiple occurrences where it shares consecutive characters with lucky, use the longest consecutive string of the characters.
- For ANY letter it shares with the word "omen" subtract 2 from the luck.

  - It can match a character any amount of times, in any order. For instance the string "nnnnnomemenn" loses 24 luck (12 matching letters)

Example:

```
luck("lucky")
>>32
```

2^5 (5 consecutive letters) = 32

```
luck("firetruck")
>>6
```

2^3 - 2 (3 consecutive letters from *uck*, *e* shared with omen)

```
luck("memes")
>>-7
```

1 - 8 (base amount, 4 shared with "omen")

This is code golf, so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.

You can input and output any way you'd like - write a function, use standard input, etc.

For functions, assume whatever data type would make sense for that language. (For example, in JavaScript, you'd be passed a `String` and return a `Number`)

Edit: You can assume any input is lowercase.

Comment: Nice first challenge!

Comment: Should the program accept uppercase input?

Comment: @busukxuan Good question - no, it doesn't need to accept uppercase input.

Comment: @cat Not sure I quite understand what you're asking. But you can just assume all input will be lowercase and you don't need to catch any uppercase input.

Comment: Can we assume an upper or lower bound on the luck of a given input? i.e. what's the smallest number of bits / data type I can get away with, or is it as big as my language can handle? that is, should it be `int8_t str_luck(const char* str);` or should it be `uint64_t str_luck(const char* str);`?

Comment: @cat I haven't thought about that, but I'd just use something reasonable - whatever makes it easiest or shortest but still works for at least the 3 test cases I mentioned (so it would need to be capable of negatives, and handle numbers larger than 32)

Comment: What's the output for `luuck`?

Comment: @msh210 8, because `uck` is the _longest_ string of consecutive matching characters

Comment: Oh, the question post says "If the word has multiple occurrences where it shares consecutive characters with lucky, use the longest consecutive string of the characters." and I missed it. Sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/), <s>36</s> <s>32</s> <s>28</s> 26 bytes

```
Œv'¸éyåiyˆ}}¯é¤go¹'ƒÖ¦Ãg·-
```

**Explanation**

```
Œv         }                  # for each substring of input
  '¸éyåi  }                   # if substring is part of "lucky"
        yˆ                    # add it to global array
            ¯é¤               # get the longest such substring
               go             # raise 2 to its length
                 ¹'ƒÖ¦Ã       # remove all chars from input that isn't in "omen"
                       g·     # get length and multiply by 2
                         -    # subtract
                              # implicitly display
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=xZJ2J8K4w6l5w6VpecuGfX3Cr8OpwqRnb8K5J8aSw5bCpsODZ8K3LQ&input=b21lbnM)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Adnan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34388/adnan)

Comment: Compression for 1 word can also be done with `'`, so for 26: `Œv'¸éyåiyˆ}}¯é¤go¹'ƒÖ¦Ãg·-` :).

Comment: @Adnan: Weird. I was certain I had tried that. Apparently not. Thanks!

Comment: why isn't this the top answer?

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES7), <s>123</s> <s>112</s> 107 bytes

```
s=>2**[5,4,3,2,1,0].find((i,_,a)=>a.some(j=>s.includes("luckyL".substr(j,i))))-2*~-s.split(/[omen]/).length
```

Edit: Saved 11 bytes thanks to @Titus by assuming that the letter `L` does not appear in the input. Saved 5 bytes thanks to @Oriol. ES6 version for <s>125</s> <s>114</s> 109 bytes:

```js
f=
s=>(1<<[5,4,3,2,1,0].find((i,_,a)=>a.some(j=>s.includes("luckyL".substr(j,i)))))-2*~-s.split(/[omen]/).length
;
```

```html
<input oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value)><pre id=o></pre>
```

Comment: Why do you use `replace([^])` instead of `match([])`? Do you waste 3 bytes or is there a reason?

Comment: @Titus How many bytes does it cost to deal with a `null` match result?

Comment: Four for a string, and a pair of `()` in this case; eating up all six that you would save with `match(/[omen]/)`. Pity.

Comment: @Titus I think I tried both and found they were the same length so stuck with the one that I preferred. (Same goes for `[5,4,3,2,1,0]` for which I could have used `[..."543210"]` - it's the same length.)

Comment: Now finally ... found a neat trick. Saves 4 bytes on my PHP and 7 for your JS: use '*lucky' for the substr, so you can go with `[1,2,3,4,5]` instead of the spread.

Comment: @Titus Not sure if that's what you meant but by adding an `L` to the end of the substr (which will never appear in the original string) I don't have to worry about extraneous matches and I can actually use the same array `[5,4,3,2,1,0]` both times, saving a whopping 13 bytes!

Comment: `-2*s.split(/[omen]/).length+2` is shorter.

Comment: `(s.match(/l?ucky?|c?ky?|l?uc?|l|y/)||[''])[0].length)` is boring code and pretty inflexible, but 20 bytes shorter.

Comment: sorry only -18, insert `|c`

Comment: @Titus Sorry, that doesn't work for strings which have multiple lucky substrings.

Comment: correct. can you match all and sort results by length? how much would that cost?

Comment: @Titus About 35, I think. Sorry.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby, <s>91</s> 87 bytes

`String#count`'s finnicky usage strikes again! (When passed a String, it counts all occurrences of each letter in the function argument instead of all occurrences of the entire string.)

[Try it online](https://repl.it/C9sa/1)

```ruby
->s{2**(z=0..5).max_by{|j|z.map{|i|s[b="lucky"[i,j]]?b.size: 0}.max}-2*s.count("omen")}
```

A version that takes in lines from STDIN and prints them: 89 bytes (86 +3 from the `-n` flag)

```ruby
p 2**(z=0..5).max_by{|j|z.map{|i|$_[b="lucky"[i,j]]?b.size: 0}.max}-2*$_.count("omen")
```

Comment: ._. that `String#count` is weird. +1 for (ab)using it. Also is it shorter to use `gets` rather than a function?

Comment: @Downgoat if I `gets` I also has to `puts` for output, so not in this case.

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> <s>26</s> 28 bytes

```
-^2le+k}#"lucky".:Q)yl@"omen
```

1 byte saved thanks to OP :-)

Explanation:

```
                                 Implicit Q as input
                .:Q              Find all substrings of input
     +k}#"lucky"                 Filter for substring of "lucky", prepend "" in case of []
    e                            Take last element, which is longest
   l                             Get its length
 ^2                              Raise two to that
                      @"omen"Q   Filter Q for characters in "omen"
                     l           Get length; counts how many characters in "omen" there are
                    y            Double that
-                                Find the difference
```

[Test it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-%5E2le%2Bk%7D%23%22lucky%22.%3AQ%29yl%40%22omen&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22lucky%22%0A%22firetruck%22%0A%22memes%22&debug=1).

Comment: I'm not an expert in Pyth but I believe you can change `"omen"` to just `"omen` and Pyth will understand

Comment: @charredgrass Oops, my mistake :-)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for string without chars form "lucky" in it. "memes" for example.

Comment: @Emigna Ah. the zero case again.... Thanks, fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby: 100 bytes

```ruby
->s{2**(m=0;4.times{|j|1.upto(5){|i|m=[i,m].max if s.match"lucky"[j,i]}};m)-s.scan(/[omen]/).size*2}
```

Comment: Try `/[omen]/` as the regex to golf it down - it will match any character and is better in practical use than chaining `|`s for single characters.

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript - 206 Bytes

```javascript
r=>{var a="lucky";r:for(var e=5;e>0;e--)for(var n=0;6>n+e;n++){var o=a.substring(n,e+n);if(r.includes(o))break r}for(var t=0,e=0;e<r.length;e++)('omen'.indexOf(r[e])+1)&&t++;return Math.pow(2,o.length)-2*t}
```

Comment: You could change this condition: `s[k]=='o'||s[k]=='m'||s[k]=='e'||s[k]=='n'` to look like this: `"oman".split("").includes(s[k])`

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! You can golf this down by removing whitespace to conserve bytes. Also, instead of `(s[k]=='o'||s[k]=='m'||s[k]=='e'||s[k]=='n')` you could use `('omen'.indexOf(s[k])+1)` (assuming this is JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Got it down to 237, although it looks like the Ruby crowd's got me beat.

Comment: Another small thing: you can shorthand `function luck(r)` down to `r=>` to just make it an anonymous function, that's all that is necessary for this challenge. Also I made an edit to the challenge so you don't have to worry about case so you can remove the `r=r.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Instead of `substring` you can use `slice` i believe (test this though, as I'm not sure)

Comment: You can use `substr(n,e)` instead of `substring(n,e+n)`. It saves a byte over @Downgoat's `slice(n,e+n)` too. Also, `"lucky"` seems to only be used once, so you can probably trim out the variable declaration and go straight for `"lucky".substr(...`

Comment: @Downgoat You are correct, they are interchangeable in this case. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 99

Another approach... I just learned about function aliasing

```
import Data.List
s=subsequences
i=intersect
l=length
f n=2^(l$last$i(s"lucky")$s n)-2*l(i n$"omen")
```

#### Usage

```
f"lucky"
32

f"firetruck"
6

f"memes"
-7
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 57 bytes

```
b=gets.count'omen'
$.+=1while/[lucky]{#$.}/
p 2**$./2-2*b
```

`gets` sets `$.` to 1 as a side effect, then we increment it until the regular expression matching `$.` consecutive lucky characters no longer matches.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 86 bytes

Code:

```
2^StringLength@LongestCommonSubsequence[#,"lucky"]-2StringCount[#,{"o","m","e","n"}]&
```

Explanation:

`LongestCommonSubsequence` returns the longest contiguous substring common to the input and `"lucky"`. `StringLength` gives its length. `StringCount` counts the number of occurrences of the characters of `"omen"` in the input.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (139 Bytes)

```
import itertools as t
s=input()
print 2**max([j-i for i,j in t.combinations(range(6),2)if'lucky'[i:j]in s]+[0])-2*sum(_ in'omen'for _ in s)
```

Comment: You can save one byte by using `from intertools import*`

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, <s>168</s> <s>157</s> <s>152</s> <s>139</s> <s>144</s> 136 bytes

EDIT: Really obvious things I should have seen easier have been changed, and some slightly less obvious.

Edit 2: stoopid (˚n˚). The program threw errors. I fixed it up. not actually 153 :(

Thanks to Leaky Nun for saving 5 bytes, and to jmilloy for saving <s>13</s> 8 bytes.

```python
s=input()
p=q=k=len(s)
m=0
while-~p:
 while-~q:m=(m,q-p)[(s[p:q]in"lucky")*q-p>m];q-=1
 p-=1;q=k
print(2**m-2*sum(i in"omen"for i in s))
```

The program runs through all possibly possible substrings in input (possibly possible, because it computes impossible substrings as well, 8 to 7, for example), checks if the substring is in "lucky", then sets the exponent of 2 to the length of the substring should it be greater than the current value. Possibly could be improved by using only one while loop. Could possibly use some improvement; I'm still getting the hang of this.

Comment: `while p+1` becomes `while-~p`

Comment: since `b=s[p:q]`, `len(b)` must be `q-p` right?

Comment: I stole you input and print method but did the rest very different, thanks! I think if you just do ```print(2**m-2*sum(i in"omen" for i in s))``` for your last three lines you'll do better, like 148?

Comment: Oh, and you can just move s[p:q] into the if clause ```while-~q:n=q-p;m=n if(s[p:q]in"lucky")*n>m else m;q-=1``` for 143?

Comment: `sum(map(s.count,"omen"))` saves one byte, making it 135

Answer (score 1):

## TSQL, 233 bytes

**Golfed:**

```
DECLARE @t varchar(99)='oluck'

,@z INT=0,@a INT=0,@ INT=1,@c INT=0WHILE @a<LEN(@t)SELECT
@a+=IIF(@=1,1,0),@z=IIF('LUCKY'LIKE'%'+x+'%'and @>@z,@,@z),@c+=IIF(x
IN('O','M','E','N'),2,0),@=IIF(@+@a-1=LEN(@t),1,@+1)FROM(SELECT
SUBSTRING(@t,@a,@)x)x PRINT POWER(2,@z)-@c
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
DECLARE @t varchar(99)='oluck'

,@z INT=0
,@a INT=0
,@  INT=1
,@c INT=0
WHILE @a<LEN(@t)
  SELECT
    @a+=IIF(@=1,1,0),
    @z=IIF('LUCKY'LIKE'%'+x+'%'and @>@z,@,@z),
    @c+=IIF(x IN('O','M','E','N'),2,0),
    @=IIF(@+@a-1=LEN(@t),1,@+1)
    FROM(SELECT SUBSTRING(@t,@a,@)x)x
PRINT POWER(2,@z)-@c
```

[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/509344/determine-the-luck-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP program, <s>139</s> 135 <s>108</s> bytes

quantum leap fails for multiple substrings where the first occurence is shorter. :(

<sup>actually I could save another 7 bytes in PHP<5.4 with register_globals on</sup>

```
<?for($s=$argv[1];$i<5;$i++)for($j=6;--$j;)$r=max($r,strstr($s,substr('lucky*',$i,$j))?2**$j:1);echo$r-2*preg_match_all('/[omen]/',$s);
```

usage: `php -d error_reporting=0 <filename> <string>`

+5 for a function:

```
function f($s){for(;$i<5;$i++)for($j=6;--$j;)$r=max($r,strstr($s,substr('lucky*',$i,$j))?2**$j:1);return$r-2*preg_match_all('/[omen]/',$s);}
```

**tests** (on the function)

```
echo '<table border=1><tr><th>input</th><th>output</th><th>expected</th><th>ok?</th></tr>';
foreach([
    'lumberjack'=>0,        'smack'=>2,
    'nnnnnomemenn'=>-23,    'lucky'=>32,
    'omen'=>-7,             'firetruck'=>6,
    'memes'=>-7,            'determine the “luck” of a string'=>0,
    'amazing'=>-3,          'wicked'=>2,
    'chucky'=>16,           'uckyuke'=>14,
    'ugly'=>2,              'lucy'=>8,
    'lukelucky'=>30
] as $x=>$e){
    $y=f($x);
    echo"$h<tr><td>",$x,'</td><td>',$y,'</td><td>',$e,'</td><td>',$e==$y?'Y':'N',"</td></tr>";
}echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell (<strike>134</strike> 132 Bytes)

```
import Data.List
c[]=[]
c s@(_:x)=inits s++c x
l=length
g q=2^(maximum$map(\z->l q-l(q\\z))$c"lucky")-2*(l$intersect q"omen")
```

Not a code golfer nor a Haskell programmer, so would love some tips on this one.

(Example: `g "firetruck"`)

Comment: I am no Haskell Expert either, but managed to carve off a few byes by changing the algorithm slightly and using function aliases on reused functions.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 155 bytes

```
def f(w:String)=(1::List.fill((for(a<-1 to 5;s<-"lucky".sliding(a))yield if(w.contains(s)) a else 0).max){2}).product-2*w.filter("omen".contains(_)).length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc) with flag `/u:System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`, 99 bytes

```cs
n=>(1<<Matches(n,"l?u?c?k?y?").OrderBy(x=>x.Value).Last().Length)-n.Count(x=>"omen".Any(c=>c==x))*2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9fS8MwFMWf108Rgg@J66JOUFj/oUNBmAhu6MPYQ8luu7AuGUmqLaVf3ZoOdaJPl3s453fP5WbEjejuS8lDY7WQuS@kjbOok1FMLsLwMbV8A4ZIHxdJmfBkm9QJpuxJr0Hf1qSK4oq9pEUJlM1SY4kbIHO7oSPJpqqUtrdgtQOJ2Y2sCY9iHkUVpafjzgu8t1QjC8ZOUwMGRUjCOyLHJnS5ajyCi5Jva@xfjqnvtkxosNpJ2L86CDvYgcH@6Jq2gedlShMXRcLhzgM3wuOFr3JOHQ6p13iDqZJGFcBetbBATnAj2gnCNPAGfTN96JSRn/xSrNiDhd3FtyNXau0s/wzj4A97JmTPh2oP3MIaNX2SLdT88Cuhre9YFjXu5G@1r9J2H2pvhaN1Z@VkXhvHZwuoLHuGvCxSfVftXcz0jl6C6hM)